# lavaan compare model with latent vs no latent

Tags: r, r-lavaan

New to Lavaan. Trying to explore the hypothesis that there is a latent variable in between my independent variables and my outcome. In graphical form trying to compare A to B:

[image]

I made a toy model:

```
library(psych)
library(lavaan)
data(bfi)
names(bfi) <- tolower(names(bfi))
mod1 <- "
gender ~ a1 + c1 + e1 "

m1 <- sem(mod1, bfi)
summary(m1)

mod2 <- "
hid1 =~ a1 + c1 + e1 
gender ~ hid1"

m2 <- sem(mod2, bfi)
summary(m2)
```

Model 2 is giving me the error:

```
Warning message:
In lavaan::lavaan(model = mod2, data = bfi, model.type = "sem",  :
lavaan WARNING: model has NOT converged!
```

Where am I going wrong in this ?

Comment: Running your example, lavaan also outputs this:
`** WARNING ** lavaan (0.5-23.1097) did NOT converge after 820 iterations
** WARNING ** Estimates below are most likely unreliable`
The model you are testing most likely has poor identification or poor starting values.
That's not a problem in the code, but in the definition of the model.

Comment: Hey thx @JuanBosco. So is that likely data dependent, or is it entirely down to the model specification? In my real data I'm essentially trying to figure out if there is a latent mediating variable between my x's and my y. I'm trying to figure out how to detect that

Comment: It can be either or both causes. In this example, if you cange the model specification to 
`"hid1 =~ a1 + e1 
gender ~ hid1"`
The model converges naturally. I think this is a question better suited to Cross Validated, as it is related more to methodology than code.

Comment: Thx @juan bosco